# Javascript is not running after adding PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

Hi I am using google analytics embed api, at first my code was working by using javascript and manually key in the token, below are my code:

```
<div id="embed-api-auth-container"></div>
<div id="chart-container"></div>
<div id="view-selector-container"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function(w,d,s,g,js,fs){
  g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(f){this.q.push(f);}};
  js=d.createElement(s);fs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
  fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics');};
}(window,document,'script'));
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

  /**
   * Authorize the user immediately if the user has already granted access.
   * If no access has been created, render an authorize button inside the
   * element with the ID "embed-api-auth-container".
   */
    gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
      'serverAuth': {
        'access_token': '<?php echo $accessToken ?>'
      }
    });


  /**
   * Create a new ViewSelector instance to be rendered inside of an
   * element with the id "view-selector-container".
   */
  var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
    container: 'view-selector-container'
  });

  // Render the view selector to the page.
  viewSelector.execute();


  /**
   * Create a new DataChart instance with the given query parameters
   * and Google chart options. It will be rendered inside an element
   * with the id "chart-container".
   */
  var dataChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
    query: {
      ids: "xxxxxxx",   
      metrics: 'ga:sessions',
      dimensions: 'ga:date',
      'start-date': '30daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'yesterday'
    },
    chart: {
      container: 'chart-container',
      type: 'LINE',
      options: {
        width: '100%'
      }
    }
  });


  /**
   * Render the dataChart on the page whenever a new view is selected.
   */
  viewSelector.on('change', function(ids) {
    dataChart.set({query: {ids: ids}}).execute();
  });

});
</script>
```

then after i add on the php code to get the refresh token the whole webpage becomes blank. When I inspected it didn't run at all, below are my PHP code

```
<?php      

require_once( '/web/google-api-php-client-2.2.1/vendor/autoload.php' );

$accessToken = initializeAnalytics();
function initializeAnalytics()
{
  $KEY_FILE_LOCATION ='/web/client_secret_917950001739-6vodhfsbpmipoh29fl3f1pkqmo7u9dhv.apps.googleusercontent.com.json';

  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client -> setApplicationName("testing");
  $client -> setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
  $client -> setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
  $client -> refreshTokenWithAssertion();
  $client -> setAccessType("offline");
  $client -> setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/testing-embed.php');
  $token = $client->getAccessToken();
  $accessToken = $token['access_token'];

  return $accessToken;
}

echo $accessToken;

?>
```

Any one know what's the problem? The Javascript is running only after i hide this 2 line of code

```
require_once( '/web/google-api-php-client-2.2.1/vendor/autoload.php' );

$accessToken = initializeAnalytics();
```

Appreciate it.

Update a screenshot for it:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xfR9.png)

Comment: Do you have any PHP warnings or errors? I'd assume it has to do with the file path or your authentication file is not readable.

Comment: @Paedda i have updated a screenshot for you, you can have a look, in the inspect cant load anything, thank for your help!

Comment: Turn on error reporting with: 

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); 

hopefully that will give you some clues

Comment: @Paedda i tried to add the error reporting, it still didnt showing anything, below are the code

Comment: $client -> setApplicationName("testing");
  $client -> setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
  $client -> setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
  $client -> refreshTokenWithAssertion();
  $client -> setAccessType("offline");
  $client -> setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/testing-embed.php');
  $token = $client->getAccessToken();
  $accessToken = $token['access_token'];
  return $accessToken;
}
echo $accessToken;
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>

Comment: ini_set and error_reporting need to be on the first lines of your PHP file.

Comment: @Scriptman i put into the first like its still the same, its possible i didnt using composer to install the google api so i cant be called? because im direct download the api file and upload via filezilla to call it